# Не могу получить выбранный элемент из SelectList - Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

Делаю простое приложение что бы немного познакомиться с Razor Pages. У меня есть две модели: `Movie` ***-1** `Genre`. Что мне нужно это при навигации на Жанры получить все фильмы ассоциированные с этим жанром и при выборе определённого фильма из листа **Genre.Movies**, перейти на страницу выбранного фильма.

Проблема с которой я столкнулся заключается в том что, когда мой **SelectList** состоит из объектов `Movie`, то при выборе элемента из листа я получаю пустой объект `Movie`, но когда у меня лист `IDs` вместо фильмов, то всё работает как нужно.

Мой код:

**Details.cshtml:**

```
<div>
<h4>Genre</h4>
<hr />
<form method="post">
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre.GenreTitle)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Genre.GenreTitle)
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <div class="form-group" style="width: 250px;">
        <label asp-for="MoviesSL" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="SelectedMovie" class="form-control"
                asp-items="Model.MoviesSL">
        </select>
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="SelectedMovie.ID" class="text-danger"></span>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Navigate" class="btn btn-info" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**Details.cshtml.cs:**

```
public Genre Genre { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Movies list")]
public SelectList MoviesSL { get; set; }
private Movie selectedMovie;
[BindProperty]
public Movie SelectedMovie 
{
    get => selectedMovie;
    set
    {
        selectedMovie = value;
        //int g = 0;
    }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    Genre = await _context.Genre.Include(m => m.Movies).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.GenreId == id);
    MoviesSL = new SelectList(Genre.Movies);

    //int g = 0;

    if (Genre == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Page();
}

public void OnPost()
{
    var k = SelectedMovie;

    //int g = 0;
}
```

Скриншоты из дебага:

[image: Пустой объект Movie]

Когда `SelectList` состоит из **айдишников** фильмов, то я получаю выбранный элемент из листа.
[image: ID вместе Movie]